# SQL Server: Same function call in CASE and ELSE part

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Following is my `CASE` statement which uses same function call in `CASE` and `ELSE` part.

```
SELECT
    CASE dbo.MyFunction(T.Id)
        WHEN 'Some Value' THEN 'Got Some Value'
        WHEN 'Other Value' THEN 'Got Other Value'
        ELSE dbo.MyFunction(T.Id)
    END
FROM SomeTable T
```

Is there a way that I can store the value returned by first function call in `CASE` part so that I can use that value later in `ELSE` part?

Actually my function has some `SELECT` statements in it and I don't want to execute those statements twice.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is a `CROSS APPLY`. e.g. `CROSS APPLY (SELECT dbo.MyFunction(T.Id) AS SomeAlias) AS C` then using `C.SomeAlias` in the case expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE id
        WHEN 'Some Value' THEN 'Got Some Value'
        WHEN 'Other Value' THEN 'Got Other Value'
        ELSE id
    END
FROM
(
    SELECT dbo.MyFunction(T.Id) AS id
    FROM SomeTable T
) AS t
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that `dbo.MyFunction` is being called under a `SELECT` statement and it takes an argument from that `SELECT` statement. In this scenario `dbo.MyFunction` can't be called independently. I have edited my question and updated the query.

Comment: Using subquery should help, answer fixed.